# most efficient way to find largest of three doubles in .NET Microframework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded

I have three doubles:

```
double[] accel = new double[3]
        {
            _Razor.Accel_X,
            _Razor.Accel_Y,
            _Razor.Accel_Z,
        };
```

What's the most efficient way to find the largest of these in NETMF?

Comment: Trying to read the Razor 9DOF AHRS from Sparkfun? Take a look at my project: http://code.google.com/p/microframework-uav/source/browse/QuadroLib/Ahrs/RazorAhrs.cs

Comment: Heheh, yep, trying to read from the 9DoF. Thanks for the link. do you know where I can find some documentation the AHRS code? There is NONE that I can find.

Comment: The original Razor code is hosted at http://code.google.com/p/sf9domahrs/ But the ASCII output was a way to much for my uC, so I modified the original firmware to be compatible with the ArduIMU binary format. It's a lot faster to parse. You can get more infos on my blog (take a look at my profile for the link). The sf9domahrs firmware is some heavily adopted ArduIUM firmware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double result = accel[0];
if (accel[1] > result) result = accel[1];
if (accel[2] > result) result = accel[2];
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

i believe it is the usual way.

`double max = max((max(accel[0],accel[1]),accel[2])`

Comment: Do you really think its a good idea to name your variables (max) the same as the macro max?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just this, right?

```
double max = _Razor.Accel_X;

if (_Razor.Accel_Y > max)
    max = _Razor.Accel_Y;

if (_Razor.Accel_Z > max)
    max = _Razor.Accel_Z;
```

Or did you want something prettier?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution with LINQ: `accel.Max();`